# A Social Network with Artificial Intelligence

Tags: social-networking, sentiment-analysis

I'm planning a Social Network with an Artificial Intelligence . that means that the SN will take the conversations (in english) .. and analyse them in order to extract the general opinion about a subject. This helps to collect information and build statistics, which will be sent then to the appropriate user.
My question is : how to organize words and grammatical rules in a database, in order to help the social network extracting a general opinion from a conversation (agree, disagree..etc)! 
thank you.

Comment: This is called [sentiment analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis).  There is already a lot of research on it.

Comment: Sentiment analysis looks for words as "like" "don't like " and constructs a general idea ...

Comment: you said you wanted a general idea.  And sentiment analysis isn't limited to obvious phrases such as "like" and "don't like".

Comment: I know it's about a complicated task. but the idea is to create a database with predefined words so that the user can't type other words such as "LOL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its very challengning task to extract text that reflects real opnions of people because machine learning is still not advanced in this area, take a look at the following example:
your program finds this sentence on some SN website:
"I made her duck"

```
what are possible options that your program will infer:
1-i cooked a duck for her
2-i "magically" transformed her into a duck"
3-i took her duck and created it.
and many other
```

so its really challenge. I suggest to take a look at NLP(natural language processing) which covers this area you're interested in

Comment: the idea is to simplify each sentence (by deleting unwanted words) then comparing this with a predifined set of words.

Comment: @Simo TAQI: Well, what about context-sensitivity? E.g. "Yeah, right" can mean exact opposites, depending on the surroundings - even though the words themselves are clear and unambiguous.

Comment: yeah, I've thought about this matter.. then the program will annalyse the post to wich the user replied. if the other post isn't understood. it will check for the prev.. untill the first post

Answer (score 1):

Could you plug Wolfram Alpha (http://www.wolframalpha.com/about.html) into your site?  That would save probably a LOT of work.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, but it may have some of the kind of functionality you're looking for.

Comment: I know wolframealpha is a good example of the AI. but I didn't know about the plugin before